# wrong parent for cardlayout with 2 class

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a Jpanel with an actionPerformed and i try to change card from a cardlayout when its activate, diaporama is my CardLayout from another class,why i have an error for wrong parent??? im a bit lost,sorry for my english :

```
public class PanelAcces extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JLabel labelIdentifiant; 
    JTextField entrerIdentifiant; 
    JLabel labelMotDePasse; 
    JTextField entrerMotDePasse; 
    JButton boutonConnexion = new JButton("Connexion");
    PanelLogiciel panelLogiciel;
    Connexion connexion;


    public PanelAcces(PanelLogiciel parLogiciel, Connexion parConnexion){
        panelLogiciel = parLogiciel;
        labelIdentifiant = new JLabel("Identifiant:");
        entrerIdentifiant = new JTextField(10);
        labelMotDePasse = new JLabel("Mot de passe:");
        entrerMotDePasse = new JTextField(10);
        connexion = parConnexion;

        this.add(labelIdentifiant);
        this.add(entrerIdentifiant);
        this.add(labelMotDePasse);
        this.add(entrerMotDePasse);
        this.add(boutonConnexion);
        boutonConnexion.addActionListener(this);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent parEvt) {
        if (parEvt.getSource() == boutonConnexion){
            try {
                if (SQL.methodeConnexion(connexion,this.entrerIdentifiant.getText(),this.entrerMotDePasse.getText()) == true){
                    this.panelLogiciel.diaporama.show(panelLogiciel.panelSite,"site");
                    System.out.println("cc");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("marche ap");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}}
```

Comment: What is the error that pops up?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
 at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.CardLayout.show(Unknown Source)
 at e_commerce.PanelAcces.actionPerformed(PanelAcces.java:44)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: error is about that line :this.panelLogiciel.diaporama.show(panelLogiciel.panelSite,"site");

Comment: @dat3450 no answer?